# how to install python distutils

Tags: python, distutils

I just got some space on a VPS server(running on ubuntu 8.04), and I'm trying to install django on it. The server has python 2.5 installed, but I guess its non standard installation. When I run install script for django, I get

```
amitoj@ninja:~/Django-1.2.1$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from distutils.core import setup
ImportError: No module named distutils.core
```

I'm stumped. All the articles on internet tell me how to install modules using distutils. But how do I get distutils itself? Can anyone point me to the archive for distutils? I looked in /usr/lib/local/python2.5, /usr/lib/python2.5 etc, and as expected there is no distutils to be found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to install setuptools when it isn't already there and you can't use a package manager is to download [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py) and run it with the appropriate Python interpreter. This works even if you have multiple versions of Python around: just run ez_setup.py once with each Python.

Edit: note that recent versions of Python 3 include setuptools in the distribution so you no longer need to install separately. The script mentioned here is only relevant for old versions of Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work. I get this "   import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5" error. The basic python installation is pretty screwed up I guess. I'll go with local install. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: That script's syntax seems out of date. At the very least it won't run in python3.6, so not a great solution currently.

Comment: @Jmills Python from 3.4 onwards includes setuptools so no need to run that script on recent versions. The question was asked about Python 2.

Comment: @Duncan Oh yes it does say Python2 - so this error can be encountered installing Python3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04, that is what brought me here, and `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` will fix it. But your note clarifies the version difference.

Comment: It appears that 14.04, 16.04 both have it "built in" but in 18.04 you need to install `python3-distutils` FWIW...

Comment: gives error for python3,
`$ python3 ~/python_setup_tools/ez_setup.py 
  File "/home/prashant/python_setup_tools/ez_setup.py", line 106
    except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
worked for python2 
`$ python2 ~/python_setup_tools/ez_setup.py 
Setuptools version 0.6c11 or greater has been installed.
(Run "ez_setup.py -U setuptools" to reinstall or upgrade.)`

Answer (score 257):

I know this is an old question, but I just come across the same issue using Python 3.6 in Ubuntu, and I am able to solve it using the following command (this works in Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

Comment: This package literally does not exist in Ubuntu 16.04. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-distutils

Comment: Worked like a charm on 18.04

Comment: Getting error E: Package 'python3-distutils' has no installation candidate in Ubuntu 18.4

Comment: Same as @Ganesh, `has no installation candidate` Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: I have this installed for python3.7 but when for python3.6 it shows no module found distutils.utils, What should I do?

Comment: It is possible to install it for the very specific version. I tried it with `sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils` after the output for `(...) python3-distutils` told, it is up-to-date at version 3.6 although i set `python3` to 3.9. and that worked

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 is better to specify version. Like @Lukas mention above:  `sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils` -> fix my problem with `python3.8`

Comment: Thanks. It's one of the quick find for me in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 30):

If you are unable to install with either of these:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

Try this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra
```

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/RDlTq8sMxro

Comment: I'm getting an error:  `Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: but my `java -version` looks okay:  `java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)`

Comment: What is the difference between `python3-distutils-extra`(on Ubuntu16.04) and `python3-distutils`(cannot locate on python3-distutils-extra)?

Comment: Per packages.debian.org: "This package (python3-distutils-extra) provides additional functions to Python's distutils and setuptools." So it would seem that distutils is a dependency of distutils-extra. Why installing distutils-extra would succeed where installing distutils fails, I cannot say.

Answer (score 16):

you can use `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` by root permission.

i believe it worked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1319047/cant-install-virtual-interpreter-in-pycharm-in-linux)

Answer (score 13):

You can install the `python-distutils` package. `sudo apt-get install python-distutils` should suffice.

Comment: Can't do that. Its a VPS server, I don't have sudo privileges. I'm thinking of installing a local python. Either that, or I find distutils archive for python 2.5.

Comment: If you are installing local Python switch to 2.6 or 2.7 They come with `distutils` bundled.

Comment: All Python have included distutils since 1999.  Here it looks like one of the stupid OSes that split the standard library into arbitrary python and python-devel packages.

Comment: It's now prepended with the python version, for me: `sudo apt install python3.8-distutils`

Answer (score 9):

I ran across this error on a Beaglebone Black using the standard Angstrom distribution. It is currently running Python 2.7.3, but does not include distutils. The solution for me was to install distutils. (It required su privileges.)

```
    su
    opkg install python-distutils
```

After that installation, the previously erroring command ran fine.

```
    python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 7):

The module not found likely means the packages aren't installed.

Debian has decided that distutils is not a core python package, so it is not included in the last versions of debian and debian-based OSes. You should be able to do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
sudo apt-get install python3-apt
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a scenario where you are using one of the latest versions of Ubuntu (or variants like Linux Mint), one which comes with Python 3.8, then you will NOT be able to have Python3.7 `distutils`, alias not be able to use `pip` or `pipenv` with Python 3.7, see:
[How to install python-distutils for old python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567990/how-to-install-python-distutils-for-old-python-versions)

Obviously using Python3.8 is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me: `sudo apt-get install python-distutils`

So, I tried this: `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`

Answer (score 0):

If the system Python is borked (i.e. the OS packages split distutils in a python-devel package) and you can’t ask a sysadmin to install the missing piece, then you’ll have to install your own Python.  It requires some header files and a compiler toolchain.  If you can’t have those, try compiling a Python on an identical computer and just copying it.

Answer (score 0):

By searching all python-distutils related package:

```
apt-cache search x
```

I get python3-distutils-extra - enhancements to the Python3 build system

Then just try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils-extra
```