# distutils and pygame for python 3.7 on a machine running python 3.8

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, distutils, carla

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. On my machine, running Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8, I'm trying to run a program which does not support Python 3.8, but it requires Python 3.7 (FYI, it is Carla Simulator).

I need pygame, but when installing it through pip (`python3.7 -m pip install pygame`) it raises an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'`

Now, I have `distutils` correctly installed and updated at version 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.
Is there any way for me to install a `distutils` version compatible with Python 3.7 without affecting Python 3.8 and related modules? Or do you have hany suggestion to get pygame for Python 3.7 and running Carla somehow? Could a virtual environment help?

My question is really similar to this one [How to install python-distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567990/how-to-install-python-distutils) but I don't actually require distutils, I just need the program to work...

Thank you

----- EDIT -----

I tried creating a virtual environment using venv, but I got an error due tue unavailability of ensurepip. Googling it, I found it might be related to the fact that my Python 3.7 version might have been installed through Anaconda (I actually can't remember). Running `apt-cache rdepends python3.7` I get:

```
python3.7
Reverse Depends:
  python3.7-minimal
```

Is it safe to completely uninstall current Python3.7 and reinstall it to hopefully get ensurepip? Any suggested code to safely do it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for you would be to run your program in a virtual environment where you would specify the default python version to be 3.7 I think (see [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) for an example). You can then install all your dependencies inside this environment and not have to deal with any conflicts between the two versions on Python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, using virtualenv I get another error related to the absence of `distutils`. Using venv instead, I get another error which I've reported in my question. No problem using 3.8, but I couldn't start the venv with a different version.

Answer (score 1):

Using pyenv you could specify the python version you want to use.
for example:
create a new folder and hit:

```
pyenv local 3.7.2
```

then create your virtual env by using pipenv:

```
pipenv install
```

then start your journey to building your game.

hope it help.

Comment: No way I can use it. `pyenv` command cannot be found. Using `pyvenv`, instead, I get a suggestion to install it through `sudo apt install python3-venv`. Running the line, I discover it is already installed...