# How to disable sanity checker

Tags: jenkins, yocto, bitbake

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I'm trying to execute `bitbake <image>` from a Jenkins job. Build fails with Error:

```
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
  Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
  Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:
  Your Python 3 is not a full install. Please install the module distutils.sysconfig (see the Getting Started guide for further information).
```

I tried to install `distutils` module (tried approaches from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810521/how-to-install-python-distutils)) but got dependency issues that was not able to fix, so as alternative solution I want to disable the sanity check

This is how `sanity.conf` looks currently:

```
# Sanity checks for common user misconfigurations
#
# See sanity.bbclass
#
# Expert users can confirm their sanity with "touch conf/sanity.conf"
BB_MIN_VERSION = "1.46.0"

SANITY_ABIFILE = "${TMPDIR}/abi_version"

SANITY_VERSION ?= "1"
LOCALCONF_VERSION  ?= "1"
LAYER_CONF_VERSION ?= "7"
SITE_CONF_VERSION  ?= "1"

INHERIT += "sanity"
```

So how to update `sanity.conf` to disable sanity checker?

Comment: The thing is, you can hack your way past this error message, but these checks are doing very basic checks - if they fail, your system most likely will not be able to build a usable image, and possibly it will just lead to a new error. E.g. this error indicates that your system will fail building `glib`, at least. If you want to experiment, you can comment out [these lines](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes-global/sanity.bbclass#n629) to get a bit further. But generally solving those dependency issues you mentioned would be more beneficial.

Comment: Like @skandigraun said, if you insist just do `INHERIT:remove = "sanity"`

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I've added `sed -i -e 's/INHERIT += "sanity"/INHERIT:remove = "sanity"/g' /path/to/conf/sanity.conf` (line for lines replacement) to Jenkins job config and at least build is started with no errors. You can add your comment as answer

Comment: Do not modify Poky directly, check point 5 of [doc](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/what-i-wish-id-known.html), check my answer.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM in #5 of doc there is something about *next release*... however I'm making a checkout to a project and doing build within the Jenkins job and the workspace cleaned before each build, so not sure how it might harm...

Comment: In general, it is not related to Next release only, that what they described as a general Alert, but, in reality, even if you're automating this, it will be a habbit and get into your mind as a normal action. So I always recommend applying the guides as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the comments, it is not recommended to disable sanity checks unless you are ready to face errors and fix them on your own.

In your `local.conf` or any other suitable `.conf` file in your environment, add:

```
INHERIT:remove = "sanity"
```

Comment: This used to get overwritten as soon as I triggered a build. I created a conf/sanity.conf file and added this line. It worked. Thanks very much for the suggestion...